# Не выполняется аутентификация по имени пользователя в Laravel 7

Tags: laravel7

Я только начал изучение Laravel 7. Я настроил аутентификацию согласно документации Laravel, зарегистрировал пользователя, перегрузил метод **username** в *LoginController*.

В форму входа ввожу имя пользователя, пароль и нажимаю кнопку "Login". Страница перегружается, но вход в систему не выполняется. Ни каких ошибок не вылетает.

Возвращаю все к дефолтному состоянию, т.е. убираю метод **username**. Аутентифицируюсь по email все проходит нормально, аутентифицированного пользователя система редиректит на home.

Подскажите, где может быть проблема?

*Используется Laravel версии 7.30.1, PHP 7.4.11 (XAMPP), ОS Ubuntu 20.10*